# Проблемы с body

Tags: html, css

Всем добрый вечер. Использую верхнею навигацию:

```
width: 100%;height: 55px;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;
```

При проверки кода "F12", BODY начинается после верхней навигации, тем самым появляется прокрутка сайта, хотя быть ее не должно. Помогите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

```
html{height: 100%;} body{height: 100%;}
```

Дальше использую блок на всю страницу с отступом в 55px (Как высота навигации).

```css
.top{width: 100%;height: 55px;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;}
.container{height: 100%;margin-top: 55px;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  ...  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: html добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @edem не совсем понял. Расскажите подробней пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавьте html разметку Вашей страницы в тело вопроса. По одному css не совсем ясна проблема.

Comment: @edem Вставил, надеюсь этого достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых нужно задать `box-sizing:border-box;`, чтоб `padding` и `border` были включены в высоту элементов.
Потом задать `height: 100%;` для html.
Для `container` убрать `margin-top` т.к. вы задаете ему высоту 100% а потом еще добавляете `margin` 55px, конечно он становиться больше экрана.
Вместо этого задать `padding-top: 55px` для `body`

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html{height: 100%;}
body{height: 100%; padding-top: 55px; margin: 0}
.top{width: 100%;height: 55px;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0; background: blue;}
.container{height: 100%; background: yellow;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  ...  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Сделал как сказали, для того чтобы убедиться все ли работает прописал следующее: для body  `background: #000;` и в container вставил блок с высотой в 1200px и задал цвет. В итоге растянулся сайт по высоте и видно границу окончания body и container и ниже опускается блок который я задал в container с черным фоном но body оканчивается выше. Проблема не до конца решена:((

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш комментарий - попробуйте для body и html вместо height: 100% задать min-height: 100%. Я думал вам нужно, чтоб сайт всегда был по высоте экрана, не больше и не меньше

Comment: помогло спасибо. Но есть еще одно, для блока который внутри container прописал margin 50px 0; для того чтобы он не прижимался к навигации. В итоге снизу все хорошо а сверху черная полоса, т.е проглядывается цвет body:((

Comment: можно попробовать вместо margin для блока внутри контейнера задать `padding: 50px 0;` для самого container, а вообще конечно ссылочку бы, тогда бы качественней подсказал, а так, тяжело не видя

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Еще вопросик, надеюсь последний. Я вот блок который внутри с высотой 1200px, задал высоту  200px и body уменьшился в размер container + padding: 50px 0; Так и должно быть? Хотя думаю что нет, если уж и торчит желтый цвет body то его границы должны быть внизу страницы а не там где оканчивается блок который в container. Такой вариант подошел бы для страниц с прокруткой, а так как в дальнейшем будут страницы без прокрутки, хотелось бы решить эту проблему.